# LINQ - return all rows for a given ID if it contains xyz

Tags: c#, linq

I find this hard to explain.

I want to return every row item of a given ID, if that ID contains certain items.

For example

```
ID State
1    NY
1    FL
1    NC
2    NY
2    FL
2    GA
2    NC
```

Filtering on a list of 'FL','GA'

this would return

```
2    NY
2    FL
2    GA
2    NC
```

not

```
2    FL
2    GA
```

and not ID 1 information because it doesn't contain GA

Comment: You should break it into two queries I guess, first get all the ids and then take all the rows

Comment: Something like `list.GroupBy(x => x.ID).Where(grp => new[]{"FL", "GA"}.All(s => grp.Any(x => x.State == s))).SelectMany(grp => grp).ToList()`?

Comment: You can use a simple nested query: `var result = data.Where(x => x.id == data.First(x => x.state == "YOURSTATE").id);`

Comment: @PhilippApe They need the id that has both states which is more complicated than that.  Not to mentions that there could be multiple ids that match and `First` would only find the first one or no matches and `First` would throw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a class that looks something like this

```
public class IdAndState
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
}
```

You can create some methods to give you an enumerable of `IdAndState` for all matching ones, or an enumerable of enumerable of these (depending on what you want).

```
public IEnumerable<IdAndState> GetResultsFlat()
{
    return GetResults().SelectMany(x => x);
}

public IEnumerable<IEnumerable<IdAndState>> GetResults()
{
    var idsAndStates = new List<IdAndState>();
    var states = new List<string>() { "FL", "GA" };
    return idsAndStates
        // get groups of IdAndStates by ID
        .GroupBy(x => x.Id)
        // select only the groups where...
        .Where(x => states
            // ... all of the states are in the IdsAndStates in the group
            .All(state => x
                .Select(idAndState => idAndState.State)
                .Contains(state)))
        // make into regular IEnumerable<>
        .Select(x => x);
}
```